# AJAX button called by another AJAX did not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a web for upload, make list, download and delete from Google Drive. all looking good ( view, and list working )
My trouble is my delete button when I click my delete button its just looping my list and said maaf. ( maaf = sorry, it does not work)

here my delete button ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function deleteItem(){
   $.ajax({
    url  : "del.php",
    type : "POST" ,
    data : {
      data_id : $no,
    },
    success: function()
    {
        var data_arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        var status   = data_arr.status;
        if(status == 'succsess'){
          location.reload();
          //alert('Maaf')
        }else{
          alert('Maaf')
          //location.reload()
        }
    }
  });       
        }
</script>
```

here My del.php

```
<?php   
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('my_id');
    $client->setClientSecret('my_secret');

    $sting = file_get_contents("token.json");
    $json_a = json_decode(file_get_contents("token.json"), true);

    $client->setAccessToken($json_a);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $folder = 'code_folder';
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 10,
        'q' => "'".$folder."' in parents",  
    );

 $no = $_POST['no'];
 $service->files->delete($no);



 $data['status'] = 'success';

 echo json_decode($data);

 ?>
```

Btw i call the button using another ajax .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url  : "list.php",
    type : "GET" ,
    success: function(data,alert_message)
    {

        var data_arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        var status   = data_arr.status;
        var result   = data_arr.data_arr;
        if(status == 'success'){
            jQuery.each( result,function( i, items){
                var content   = '<tr id="'+items.no+'">';
        content  += '<td>';
                    content  += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" data_id="'+items.no+'">delete</a>';
                    content  += '</td>';

                    content  += '</tr>';

                $('.list').append(content);

      $('.btn-delete').on('click', function() {

       //console.log("");
        $no = $(this).data("no");
        deleteItem($no);
      });

            }); 
            }else{
            alert('Gomenasai');
        }

    }       

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a quick look over your code you seem to be calling

```
deleteItem($no)
```

but in your function you are not allowing for any parameters.

```
function deleteItem()
```

To pass the variable you need to allow for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function deleteItem(no){
   $.ajax({
    url  : "del.php",
    type : "POST" ,
    data : {
      data_id : no,
    },
    success: function()
    {
        var data_arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        var status   = data_arr.status;
        if(status == 'succsess'){
          location.reload();
          //alert('Maaf')
        }else{
          alert('Maaf')
          //location.reload()
        }
    }
  });       
        }
</script>
```

Comment: still did not work.. 
when i open del.php it's said

Notice: Undefined index: no in C:\xampp\htdocs\tgs_mp\del.php on line 20

Comment: You would need to be more specific for what line 20 is?

Comment: at line 20 it is `$no = $_POST['no']; $service->files->delete($no);` which means you need to pass the argument as 'no'. ie. `data: { 'no': no}` in the ajax code

Comment: It's really hard to help when you are so vague.  Are you getting console errors? What part isn't working?

Comment: sorry, 
I am using inspect element(Q) .
in console tap it say :
ReferenceError: no is not defined[Learn More]        tgs_mp:280:11 
that line is :
data_id : $no,

Comment: what did you use with your function? function deleteItem(no){ or function deleteItem($no){

Comment: thx guys i already found my prob..
its in my javascript 
its should data-id
but mine is data_id..